# Unable to set the imageView to the first position in Custom ListView in android

Tags: android, listview

I want to set the image icon to only the  first (0) position of the listView and no image to the rest of the list items.However, when I scroll down the  some image View randomly pops out, like in the 10th  position . Here is the sample code . There are some additional code in here, but please do not mind . For now I want to list only on the first list item. I do not want ImageView to pop up at random points.

```
    if(position==0){

//ignore this part
          if(!newIconParam.get(0).equals("OK")||newIconParam.get(0)!="OK"){
                if (loto_date.get(0).trim().toString().equals(today)) {
                    logicflag = true;
                    holder.left.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blinker);
                    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) holder.left.getBackground();
                    frameAnimation.start();

                }else if(!loto_date.get(0).trim().toString().equals(today)&&position==0){
                    holder.left.setImageResource(R.drawable.new_icon);
                    // holder.left.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
                }
          }else{

          }

    }else{
          holder.left.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with my emulator. When I activated my app on a real device , everything went smoothly.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly remove the src of ImageView from xml file and set the image only in 0 position as

```
if(position==0)
{
 holder.left.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
}
```

Comment: The problem is I hadn't set the image in the xml , however, when I scroll the list item , the image that has been set in the if(position == 0 ) condition shows up in the list items position that is not in the 0th position.